# Effective UID doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

## Code

I wrote the following c program to print the real and effective uid:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void main() {
    printf("real uid: %d\n", (int) getuid());
    printf("effective uid: %d\n", (int) geteuid());
}
```

I compiled it using gcc:

```
jazz@kryptonite beyond_basics $ gcc -o uid_demo.out uid_demo.c
```

Afterwards I changed owner and permissions as following:

```
jazz@kryptonite beyond_basics $ sudo chown root:root uid_demo.out
jazz@kryptonite beyond_basics $ sudo chmod u+s uid_demo.out
```

## Result

Now I got:

```
jazz@kryptonite beyond_basics $ ll uid_demo.out
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 8712 Sep  8 18:12 uid_demo.out*
```

When running the program I get the following result:

```
jazz@kryptonite beyond_basics $ ./uid_demo.out
real uid: 1000
effective uid: 1000
```

## Question

I would expect the effective uid to be 0.

Can anyone explain why it is not?

Thanks

Comment: You set the sticky bit, he? That means, a non root user can execute the code/ privileged instructions in the code. Afaik it does not give your user root privileges during runtime, just because You execute the program.

Comment: check the mount options; probably `nosuid` has been set

Comment: Right,  this is plausible

Comment: @icbytes that isn't the sticky bit - it's the setuid bit, and it should work as described (sets the EUID to the UID of the executable file). The sticky bit would appear as `-rwxr-xr-t`

Comment: Oh, sorry. Anyway, thx for reminding me.

Comment: @icbytes - no problem ... looking forward to finding out the truth here :-) .... perhaps it's something crazy, like _"root's username was changed to 'jazz', and my username was changed to 'root'_ .. so UID of file was really 1000, and he was running as uid=0 all along... no, then realuid would be 0... ok, whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* surprising, isn't it?

It's worth checking the mount options on your filesystem - it may have been mounted with the `nosuid` option. To inspect the options, try running the `mount` command, or `cat /proc/mounts`.

(I'm sure you know which filesystem you are in, but for completeness, if you are cd'ed there, as per your example, you can use `df .` )

Comment: Yep, I've got these mount options:
`/home/jazz/.Private /home/jazz ecryptfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=53fa347e3d1f5673,ecryptfs_sig=58c68ab1391f0d15,ecryptfs_cipher-aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0 0`

So quick research showed me that I can _set_ the nosuid option like this:
`mount -o remount,noexec,nosuid,nodev /home/jazz`
But how can I unset it?

Comment: @Tschasmine That command looks good, but just change the `nosuid` to `suid`.